# Как определить угол поворота изображения?

Tags: python, opencv

Есть круглый предмет с выгравированной надписью в центре. Как определить угол поворота данного предмета с учётом надписи? Сейчас нахожу все контуры и вписываю прямоугольники/эллипсы, получающиеся углы меньше 180 градусов, т.к. текст в этом случае не учитывается.

Comment: Если надпись длинная, попробуйте обработать таким образом, чтобы надпись слилась в единый блок (blur или dilation)

Comment: @MBo если надпись сольётся в один блок, то верх-низ пропадёт? Тогда я нужный угол не получу.

Comment: Если надпись сольётся в эллипс, то можно найти направление его большой оси. А для чего нужен верх и низ?

Comment: @MBo Надпись в эллипс и сейчас вписывается. Если верха-низа нет, то вне зависимости, повернули мы на 90 или на 270, opencv показывает 90. Мне надо знать, на какой угол довернуть изображение, чтобы получить исходное. Либо угол + сторону, в которую вращать.

Comment: Так какие признаки переворота на 180 есть - буквы, что ли, распознавать? Пора уже показать картинку.

Comment: @MBo Да, из признаков переворота только буквы. Пытался тессерактом распознать, не получается. Картинку приложить не могу.